# Methods : Make my method with many input variables with out overloading

Tags: android, methods, overloading

is there Any Way To Make my Method Take many input variable but with out overloading ... could be my question not clear ... I mean Like That :

**if I Have This Method**

```
public void setValues (int val1,int val2 ,String val3){
}
```

**what I want is :** use this method with many way

```
setValues (val1,val2)
```

**OR**

```
setValues (val3)
```

**why I want to do that with out overloading :** Because if i have as example 10 variable i want to add many method with overloading but i don't like that  ...

is there any way helps me to check variable or skip it in the same method ..

Thanks for help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use varargs future to partially solve your problem http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html
This can be done if you have parameters of a same type.

But it will require that you will pass variables with the same type as a last param. It is not completely what you want, but it is a small workaround.

Comment: thanks my friend its really help if you have all your variables same type , but i have a method with more 10 variables with defferent types and i can't believe i must to add more than 6 method for just one thing

Comment: It is Java world. It has some limitations.

Answer (score 0):

No there's no way to do that in Java without method overloading. One alternative would be to group those parameters which are related and make them fields of a class. Then the method would take an instance of that class as a parameter, and which ever parameters were optional would then be null.